# UNION DISTINCT faster than OR on 9 million records?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have an InnoDB table with +- 9 million records.

I used to have a query like this

```
SELECT
  my_primary_key
FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  col1 = 1 AND
  col2 = 2 AND
  (col3 = 'aaa' OR col4 = 'bbb' OR col5 = 'ccc')
```

My table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
  `my_primary_key` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `col2` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `col3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `col4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `col5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`my_primary_key`),
  KEY `col1` (`col1`),
  KEY `col2` (`col2`),
  KEY `col3` (`col3`),
  KEY `col4` (`col4`),
  KEY `col5` (`col5`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Based on my friend suggestion, i tried to change it into

```
SELECT my_primary_key FROM my_table WHERE col1 = 1 AND col2 = 2 AND col3 = 'aaa'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT my_primary_key FROM my_table WHERE col1 = 1 AND col2 = 2 AND col4 = 'bbb'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT my_primary_key FROM my_table WHERE col1 = 1 AND col2 = 2 AND col5 = 'ccc'
```

But when i tried to see the running queries, i see that the "time" is still quite high (between 8-20 seconds)

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

Am i on the correct path by using UNION DISTINCT ? Or is there other faster way to execute my query?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say don't know what the index selectivity is, normally you don't index a TINYINT column because off the low selectivity. but if columns col1 and col2 have a higher selectivity you could make a convering index on that so you can use an delivered table and a JOIN to filter out non matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the `or` would generally be the fastest.  However, it would seem to require a full table scan.  You could try a composite index on `(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, my_primary_key)` which might get used instead of the scan.

The `union distinct` would be faster if each clause can use the index and there are relatively few rows returned.  As such, try running it with the following indexes:

```
mytable(col1, col2, col3, my_primary_key)
mytable(col1, col2, col4, my_primary_key)
mytable(col1, col2, col5, my_primary_key)
```

In your optimization, you are trying to avoid a full table scan.  The `union distinct` might achieve this with the right indexes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. However i am facing another issue if i want to add some indexes, the last time i tried, it took a long time to add some indexes (maybe because i have lot of data). Do you have any suggestion how to change table structure quickly?

Comment: Alter table on a InnoDB table with 9 million records can take a while but it depens what index you are changing and depens on the InnoDB engine version.. new InnoDB engine version support an feature thats called fast index creation, mysql version > 5.5 is should be the version that supports on default that nice feature.